# SQL Server 2012 Vs PDW

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-pdw

We are migrating to SQL server 2012 to PDW.
Any SQL script for Comparing the data between SQL server 2012 and Parallel dataware house or any tools to compare.

Answer (score 1):

This paper turned in to be very handy for me, but you will still have to do some changes in your script

http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/6/42616D71-3488-46E2-89F0-E516C10F6576/SQL_Server_to_SQL_Server_PDW_Migration_Guide.pdf